# Hibernate query aggregation

Tags: hibernate

I have two tables as:

```
B:
id | Amount | createON
1  |  1000  | 2015-01-20
2  |  10    | 2014-01-20

C:
id | Amount | B_id 
1  |  100   | 1
2  |   30   | 2
3  |   20   | 1
```

I am trying to get the a list of object which will have sum(A.amount), sum(b.amount), month and year that A was created:

```
hql.append("Select sum(b.amount), sum(c.amount), month(b.createOn), year(b.createOn)")
                .append(" from B as b, C as c")
                .append(" WHERE b = c.b")
                .append(" group by month(b.createOn), year(b.createOn)")
                .append("ORDER BY year(b.createOn) desc, month(b.createOn) desc");
                ;
```

With the query above, I expected that I would get the a list of size 2 with the result of index of 0 would be

```
1000
120
1
2015
```

However, the result I got is :

```
2000
120
1
2015
```

I have no idea how I can get the sum(b.amount) double. Is there anything wrong with my query? Any suggestion please!

Comment: what is A? show all related structures and relations, your question is a little unclear, also show the result you currently get with above query and also expected result

Comment: It is a type, it should be B_id. I edited it

Comment: take a look at it again, are you sure the result `130` in the expected result should not be `120`? or I'm wrong

Comment: No, it my typo again >.<. Sorry about that. Only the first result is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think in fact you need and equivalent HQL query of this:

```
select b.amount, sum(c.amount), month(b.createOn), year(b.createOn) from 
 C join (select id,createON,SUM(Amount) from B group by id,createON) B
 On C.B_id=c.B_id
 Group by month(b.createOn), year(b.createOn)
 ORDER BY year(b.createOn) desc, month(b.createOn) desc
```

so the **HQL** query you need is (not sure if working properly because I didn't test it):

```
"Select (select SUM(p.Amount) from c.b p), sum(c.amount),
 month(b.createOn), year(b.createOn)
 from B as b, C as c
 WHERE b = c.b
 group by (select SUM(p.Amount) from c.b p), month(b.createOn), year(b.createOn)
 ORDER BY year(b.createOn) desc, month(b.createOn) desc"
```